# Saving grid map in crsm_slam, how to?

Tags: ros, navigation, mapping, map-saver, map-server

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,

I have been using the [crsm_slam](http://wiki.ros.org/crsm_slam) package so far nicely. I am however unable to save the grid map using the command :

```
rosrun map_server map_saver -f map
```

The node gives the message : `Waiting for the map`
and nothing happens. I had to ctrl-c to kill the map_server, but the map is not saved.

Can someone suggest a way to save the map or what could be the problem?

Thanks

Alex

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/203745/saving-grid-map-in-crsm_slam,-how-to?/) by [AlexR](https://answers.ros.org/users/21013/alexr/) on ROS Answers with karma: 654 on 2015-02-24

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

By default ros map_saver subscribes to topic name `"map"` to save grid map.

And by default crsm_slam publishes map on topic   `"/slam/occupancyGridMap"` .    [check here](https://github.com/etsardou/crsm-slam-ros-pkg/blob/hydro-devel/crsm_slam/config/crsm_slam/crsm_slam_parameters.yaml)

So, to save map

```
 rosrun map_server map_saver map:=/slam/occupancyGridMap -f map
```

---

Originally posted by [bvbdort](https://answers.ros.org/users/9486/bvbdort/) with karma: 3034 on 2015-02-27

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [AlexR](https://answers.ros.org/users/21013/alexr/) on 2015-03-02**:
thank you this solved my problem.